# measure for two different network

Tags: social-network

I want to distinguish two networks. One of two has some conspicuous hub node like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEyTP.png). The other is randomly conneted. In this case, is there appropriate measure to distinguish between two networks?

Comment: You need a bit more detail on what you want. For example, is a hub node one that is path-connectedto all other nodes in the graph? Then you can define a unique node by minimizing the average path length to all other nodes

Comment: I am sorry, I had to denote that hub 'nodes'. I means that network with conspicuous hub nodes.